# Evaluating string constants from enums in Intellisense

Tags: c++, visual-studio, constants, intellisense

Is there a way to get Intellisense to evaluate string constants based on enumeration values?

Here's what I've tried:

```
#define MessageIdToName(ID) \
  (::MessageIdRange::LocalMessageStart <= ID && ID <= ::MessageIdRange::LocalMessageEnd) ? \
    ("Local Message") : \
  (::MessageIdRange::CANMessageStart <= ID && ID <= ::MessageIdRange::CANMessageEnd) ? \
    ("CANMessage") : \
  (::MessageIdRange::GlobalMessageStart <= ID && ID <= ::MessageIdRange::GlobalMessageEnd) ? \
    ("Global Message") : \
  ("Unknown")

namespace
{
  static const char* MessageIdToNameFn(const uint32_t ID)
  {
    return
      (::MessageIdRange::LocalMessageStart <= ID && ID <= ::MessageIdRange::LocalMessageEnd) ?
        ("Local Message") :
      (::MessageIdRange::CANMessageStart <= ID && ID <= ::MessageIdRange::CANMessageEnd) ?
        ("CANMessage") :
      (::MessageIdRange::GlobalMessageStart <= ID && ID <= ::MessageIdRange::GlobalMessageEnd) ?
        ("Global Message") :
      ("Unknown");
  }

  static const char* found = MessageIdToName(1025);
  static const char* foundFn = MessageIdToNameFn(1025);
}
```

Where MessageIdRange is an enum and xMessageStart/End are enum values.

I'd expect Intellisense to be able to tell me what found and/or foundFn are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that intelisense (in VS2013) doesn't show pointer content:

```
static const char* test = "test"; // Nothing for intelisense :-(
```

but it show the content of array:

```
static const char test2[] = "test"; // intelisense shows the content of test2 :-)
```

So if you change `static const char* found` to `static const char found[]`, intelisense will show the content of `found`.

And as VS2013 doesn't support `constexpr` yet, the version with the function cannot be known at compile time.

Comment: Interestingly that doesn't compile though. `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'const char []'` You can replicate the error using a very simple `const char found[] = (true ? "A" : "B");`